# Streaming replication version between different minor versions

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.4

I want to know few details about streaming replication.

I want to setup streaming replication between version 9.4.4 and 9.4.20 ?

I have the master server in centos6.6 with postgres version 9.4.4 which is a physical machine and we have created a new virtual machine centos7.5 and postgres version is 9.4.20. I want to know if this will cause any problem due to version mismatch.

Also, How can I download specific minor version 9.4.4 of postgres ? I checked some official documentation and by yum I am able to see only 9.4 which is actually 9.4.20 after I installed.

Comment: Why not upgrade the master from 9.4.4 to 9.4.20 first? And then setup replication?

Comment: Well, we can't do the upgrade as of now. Other option comes out to be installing 9.4.4. version in slave server. Can you suggest/help with that ? Also, if we somehow managed to accept the app team for upgrade to 9.4.20, how we can do that? I checked regarding "pg_upgrade" but it is used for major releases not minor releases. Thanks for your help

Comment: The minor upgrade is usually much easier. Stop the database, replace binaries, restart (and even better take a backup first, just in case).

Comment: Thanks, Any suggestion on how to get 9.4.4 rpm of postgres ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I mainly work with Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe in Postgres RPM repository? https://yum.postgresql.org/  or [PostgreSQL RPM Building Project](https://yum.postgresql.org/howtoyum.php)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it will work and documentation says, it should work.

> In general, log shipping between servers running different major
>   PostgreSQL release levels is not possible. It is the policy of the
>   PostgreSQL Global Development Group not to make changes to disk
>   formats during minor release upgrades, so it is likely that running
>   different minor release levels on primary and standby servers will
>   work successfully. However, no formal support for that is offered and
>   you are advised to keep primary and standby servers at the same
>   release level as much as possible. When updating to a new minor
>   release, the safest policy is to update the standby servers first — a
>   new minor release is more likely to be able to read WAL files from a
>   previous minor release than vice versa.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/warm-standby.html

For upgrade process

If you installed PostgreSQL via yum, yum update postgresql* should work. If you need rpms here is the PostgreSQL download link;

http://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.4/redhat/